# How to scroll backwards when displaying file using "more" command?

Tags: unix, more

Return scrolls forward. How do I scroll backward one line at a time?

Comment: I disagree with your choice of accepted answer. [The cYrus's answer](http://superuser.com/a/388009/519769) provides a more constructive/universal solution.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский when using an embedded system that doesn't have less, and there's no practical way to install it, cYrus's answer is not helpful. Given how ubiquitous IoT devices with an OS with unusable half baked compliance with open sources are, I would hardly call "just use less" as a universal solution either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's only one operating system where what Shadok says in comments to another answer is actually the case.  It isn't even a Unix.  Guess which operating system is the one whose `more` command(s) only give(s) you the Unix user experience of 1988.

### On Solaris:

You have two choices of `more` command: `/usr/bin/more` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/more`.  The former doesn't have a back one line command.  But the latter *does*.  It is <kbd>k</kbd>, optionally prefixed by a number to indicate a different number of lines.  The `xpg4` in the directory name references the *X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4*, a 1992 standard for Unices that preceded the *Single Unix Specification*.

#### Further reading

- [*more(1), page(1)*](http://shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman1/more.1.html).  SunOS man pages. 1997.

### On FreeBSD and MacOS 10:

`/usr/bin/more` and `/usr/bin/less` are links to the same file, which is GNU `less`.  Invoked via `more` it tries to follow the POSIX/SUS specification for `more`.  The Single Unix Specification specifies that the command for scrolling back one (or more) lines is <kbd>k</kbd>, optionally prefixed by a number to indicate a different number of lines, just like Solaris.

#### Further reading

- [*more(1)*](http://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=more&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9-current).  FreeBSD man pages.  2009.
- [*more*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/more.html).  The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6.  2004.
- [*more(1)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/more.1.html).  MacOS 10 manual pages. 2008.

### On Linux:

The `more` command is the BSD `more` version 5.19, from 1988.  It doesn't have a key sequence for going backwards by a line, only one for going backwards by a screenful.

#### Further reading

- [*more(1)*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/more).  Linux man page.  1992.

Answer (score 20):

Use `less` instead.

> Less is a program similar to more (1), but which allows backward  movement in the file as well as forward movement.

Comment: From the manpage of 'more' => "More is a filter for paging through text one screenful at a time.  This version is especially primitive.  Users should realize that less(1) provides more(1) emulation and extensive enhancements."

Comment: In some Unixes, more and less are links to the same program!

Comment: so "less is more" is what you are saying?

Comment: That is more or less what he was saying.

Comment: `more` and `less` produce very different results when used on `/etc/hostname` (or any other file whose content fits in one screen). With `-FX` options, `less` will behave like `more` though. I now use `alias more='less -FX'`

Answer (score 13):

#### Scroll backwards with <kbd>b</kbd>.

This worked for me for `more` where `more -V` gives

> more from util-linux 2.25.2

From the [`man` page of `more`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html):

```
b or ^B
    Skip backwards k screenfuls of text. Defaults to 1. Only
    works with files, not pipes.
```

---

For context, this was in a Postgres 9.6.1 Docker container where `uname -a` returns

> Linux 85c8072dc7eb 4.9.4-moby #1 SMP Wed Jan 18 17:04:43 UTC 2017
> x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4):

I came in to find an answer quickly but couldnt find one hence went back to the good old 
`man more`

you can use `k` to scroll a line backwards or `[n]k` to scroll back n lines

Answer (score 0):

From `more`, use `v` to start vi or vim, then `CTRL-E` to move downward line by line, and `CTRL-Y` to move upward line by line.